# using .htaccess to hide file url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need some help figuring out how to write this `.htaccess`.

My file is in `mywebsite/part5/thanksfordownload.html`. How to use `.htaccess` to have url `mywebsite/thankyoufordownload.html`?

I tried using this for the `.htaccess` but no dice. I tried uploading it both in the root and in the folder itself.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /part5/$1 [L]
```

Not sure what went wrong in this part,
thanks for your views & comments in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so basically if you **only** want that rule - you'd want to do something like this -

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^thankyoufordownload.html$ /part5/thankyoufordownload.html [L]
```

Comment: @zer - yes :)  Caught that just after I posted.

Comment: argh, cannot strike text in comments :-S +1

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
RewriteRule ^thankyoufordownload.html$ part5/thanksfordownload.html
```

This will only work for the example asked about.